# Performing Full Repair after Migrating to Incremental Repair on Cassandra Nodes

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

We are currently running Cassandra v 3.0.5 on all our nodes. We recently migrated our nodes to perform incremental repairs.  However, in the documentation, it states that incremental repairs should be run daily and full repairs weekly or monthly.  We perform a parallel, incremental repair on each node by running

> nodetool repair

And we will peform a sequential, full repair on each node by running

> nodetool repair -full -seq

My concern is with running a full repair since we migrated.  Can I just use the above command on each of the nodes or are there any other steps that I should perform first?  I just want to make sure that we do not have to perform steps like the ones we used during the migration process:

- Disable autocompaction on the node.
- Run a full, sequential repair.
- Stop the node.
- Set the repairedAt metadata value to each SSTable that existed before you * disabled compaction.
- Restart Cassandra on the node.
- Re-enable autocompaction on the node.

Any advice would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: I have the same question, did you figure out the answer? Thanks.

Comment: Also looking for this answer.

Answer (score 1):

This answer might come much later than you wanted, but no, you don't need to do those steps. If you run into issues with repairing large partitions, I recommend you use [Reaper](http://cassandra-reaper.io/). Actually, this tool is so useful that I suggest you use it anyway.